# Google Universal Analytics - setting custom attributes

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-analytics, universal-analytics

I am attempting to use Google Universal Analytics API to track events (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/).

Is it possible to send/force some attributes, like operating system, event timestamp, location, and so on?
I can't seem to find this in the documentation.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Analytics added new properties to override the IP and User-Agent, so that takes care of os name and location. Here for more info: https://github.com/brsanthu/google-analytics-java/issues/8

As for the timestamp, I created a custom dimension.

Answer (score 0):

Operating system, time down to the next minute and location (as determined by IP) is already available.

And yes, you can create custom dimensions with an event hit. You need to create your dimensions in the property settings, custom definitions (set scope to hit). The dimension gets a numeric index when you create it starting from 1. In the code you use the word dimension plus the numeric index to address your dimension:

```
ga('send', 'event', 'category', 'action', {'dimension1': "a custom value"});
```

Custom dimensions are not visible per default in standard reports, either select one of them as second dimension or create a custom report.

Comment: what I meant was override those values. I.e. I have a bunch of events stored in my DB and want to make them available in gua.